# How to move title of header for it to line up with main content of the page?

Tags: html, css, header, title

I have a row with columns on my main content section and i gave it a width of 1000px and centered it with margin:0 auto. Currently my title of the header is all the way to the left of course and i want it to line up right where the row will begin. How can i achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zck9c8ud/

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <h1>title of page</h1>
            <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>




<div class="row">
    <div class="col">col1</div>
    <div class="col">col1</div>
    <div class="col">col1</div>
</div>


*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}

header{

background:orange;
color:white;
padding:10px;
}

header h1{
display:inline;
position:relative;
left:200px;
}



nav ul{
display:inline;
}

nav ul li{
display:inline-block;
color:white;
position:relative;
left:70px;
}

.row{
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.col{
background:#999;
width:33%;
float:left;
margin:10px;
padding:10px;
color:white;
height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Give it the same width and margin? Also, your `<ul>` is invalid HTML; the only valid children of a `<ul>`, or `<ol>`, are `<li>` elements. Nothing else. At all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question properly, but here's how I tried to solve it:

TLDR: Just check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/LLzmseoq/

First, I just wrapped the header and the row in a separate container called `.wrapper`, which I gave a width of `1000px`.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>title of page</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">col1</div>
    <div class="col">col1</div>
    <div class="col">col1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I changed the width of `.row` to `800px` and the the width of `h1` to `200px` (adjust these values if you want`.

Then I floated them to separate directions so that they will sit beside each other.